# How to select circle from circle List to remove from JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, graphics2d, mouselistener

I have a JFrame that has randomly circles in it(They are generated randomly). I want to remove the selected circles by mouse click from Jframe and increase the score according to that removing.. Any idea?

"I have a timer that can able to create a new circle on the screen.
Also i have used List to store created circles. (Referring Public Circle class)
I have a shrinking feature as well for shrinking circles in time by reducing radius."

```
private static final int WIDTH = 700;
private static final int HEIGHT = 700;
public int x, y; 

private static final int D_W = 500;
private static final int D_H = 500;

private List<Circle> circles;
Random random = new Random();
public int randRadius;
public int delay = 50; 
public static int Life=10;
public static int Score=0;
        private List<Circle> circles;
public static int Score=0;
    public GameModel() {
                setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT); //setting the Frame width and height                 
                circles = new ArrayList<>();
                Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                 //timer for creating a new ball on JFrame
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        int randX = random.nextInt(D_W);  //or whatever the width of your panel is
                        int randY = random.nextInt(D_H);  //or whatever the height of your panel is
                        randRadius = random.nextInt(101) + 50; //radius
                        Color color = Color.BLUE;

                        Circle circle = new Circle(randRadius, color, randX, randY);
                        circles.add(circle);
                        update(); //it is simply repaint();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }

    @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //draw the circle randomly
                super.paintComponent(g);      
                for (Circle circle : circles) {         
                circle.drawCircle(g);     
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
            }
    public class Circle { //class for shrinking the balls in time
                public int radiuss, x, y;
                Color color;

                public Circle(int radius, Color color, int x, int y) {
                    this.radiuss = radius;
                    this.color = color;
                    this.x = x;
                    this.y = y;
                    ActionListener counter = new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                            update();
                            radiuss--;
                        }};
                        new Timer (delay, counter).start();
                }

                public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {
                    g.setColor(color);
                    g.fillOval(x, y, radiuss * 2, radiuss * 2);                 
                }
            }

    private class ClickCircle extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    selected = null;
                    ...                     
                    if (selected != null) {
                        Score++;
                        System.out.println("Score" + Score);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 2):

Don't create your own Circle class. Instead you can use the `Ellipse2D.Double(...)` class.

The Ellipse2D class implements the `Shape` interface. The `Shape` interface implements a `contains(...)` method. So you can iterate through all the Objects in your List and check if the `Shape` contains the mouse point.

So I would call change you "Circle" class to be a "ShapeInfo" class. This class would contain two properties:

1. the Shape
2. the Color

So your basic code would be:

```
//Circle circle = new Circle(randRadius, color, randX, randY);
//circles.add(circle);
Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(...);
ShapeInfo info = new ShapeInfo(shape, color);
shapes.add( info );
```

In the future you could even add `Rectangle` shapes or any other Shape that you want to your List.

See [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more general info on this concept.

```
update(); //it is simply repaint();
```

Then just invoke repaint(). That is the proper method to invoke to make sure the component is repainted properly.

Comment: but how to shrink the circle in ShapeInfo class then? without having radius.. @camickr

Comment: Or read the Ellipse API. You can reset the shape of the ellipse, or you could even create a new Ellipse object and just change the width/height of the ellipse. You don't need to have a radius to do something like this. The AffineTransform would be more generic in that is would work on any Shape, but then you would need extra information to track how much the Shape has shrunk.